# Using SQLite parameter substitution for values as well as NULL

Tags: python, sqlite, null, isnull

I would like to find the rows which fulfill certain conditions with their values. The values and, hence, the parameters for filtering can be a real number or `NULL`.

As an example, consider the following database:

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")
c = conn.cursor()
c.executescript("CREATE TABLE tab (value INTEGER); INSERT INTO tab VALUES (NULL), (42);")
```

Now, I am looking for a parameter substitution variant which is able to handle `NULL` as well as non-`NULL` values.

```
print(c.execute("SELECT * FROM tab WHERE value=?", (42,)).fetchall())
--> [(42,)]
print(c.execute("SELECT * FROM tab WHERE value=?", (None,)).fetchall())
--> []
```

As can be seen, the latter one does not work. Do I have to check the values for `None` for all parameters I use for filtering in order to use the `IS NULL` syntax?

```
print(c.execute("SELECT * FROM tab WHERE value IS NULL").fetchall())
--> [(None,)]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SQLite, the IS operator also handles non-NULL values:

```
c.execute("SELECT * FROM tab WHERE value IS ?", (anything,))
```